# Какими инструментами лучше реализовать данный интерфейс?

Tags: yii

Есть ли спец инструменты или какие-то правила для того чтобы темы выводились например как тут [pinterest](http://pinterest.com/). В общем смысл в том, что будет некоторый набор информации, который при скроллинге вниз будет расширяться.
PS Использую фреймворк yii

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Берёте Wordpress
2. Устанавливаете [подходящую тему](http://devstand.com/design/pinterest-wordpress-themes/) ([демо](http://www.apptha-demo.com/template/pinboard/))

**UPD.**

- Вот ещё вариант - [пример
     автоподгрузки блоков на jquery](http://php5lab.com/jquery/scrollup.html).
- [Расширение для Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiinfinite-scroll/)

Comment: Очень смешно. Человек использует Yii, а вы ему вордпрес предлагаете...

Comment: Я просто предлагаю готовое решение. Зачем изобретать велосипед, если всё уже готово. К тому-же и бесплатно.

Comment: Спасибо, демо версию скачала. Буду использовать как шпоргалку и подстрою для своего сайта

Answer (score 0):

"Спец интефейсов" нету. Читайте доки. А пример который вы показали легко реализовать.

Comment: опечаталась=)